# WhereIn and relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables:

- articles
- tags
- article_tag

They are both many to many relationships with a pivot.

I need to query this to get all articles that have an array of tags:

```
Article::with('tags')->whereIn('id', $tagIdArray)->get();
```

The problem with the above is that it's returning articles that have the id of $tagIdArray. How can I constraint the results so that I use the whereIn on the tags relationship?

Answer (score 9):

You've got the right idea, but a little off the ball. Using the `with('tags')` functions just pulls your Articles out with the related Tags, queries chained after the `with()` function still apply to the Articles model.

To query a relation you can do the following

```
$tagIdArray = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];

$articles = Article::whereHas('tags', function($query) use ($tagIdArray) {
    /**
      * Now querying the Tags relation. So anything in this closure will query the Tags
      * relation, but outside of the closure, you're back to querying the Articles.
      */
    $query->whereIn('id', $tagIdArray);
})->get();
```

Heres the Laravel docs on querying relations http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations

Answer (score 1):

This is how I pull products by filtering data at the Model's Relationship level.

```
$youMayAlsoLike  = Category::whereHas('product', function($query)
   {
      $query->whereIn('category_slug', ['gift-sets','multi-shade-sticks','eye pencil']);
   })
   ->inRandomOrder()
   ->take(10)
   ->get();
```